# concatenate string with date in SAS eg

Tags: string, function, date, sas, concatenation

I need to create a computed column in SAS with the combination of the string 'ULPDT_' and the result from the today() function. so that my result looks like this: ULPDT_20190101. Here is my non-functional code for the advanced expression:

```
t1.SourceFile='ULPDT_'||PUT(today(), yyddmmn8.)
```

Comment: A good question will also show any notes, warnings, or errors that are observed in the log. As for `0101` which is month and which is day ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

year-day-month, `YYYYDDMM`, is not a normal representation for date, you might actually want year-month-day `YYYYMMDD`

`t1` is indicative of an EG generated join wherein the `t1` is a table alias.  If you are editing the code of a join node, and the problematic statement is part of a `select` clause, the correct SQL syntax might be

```
'ULPDT_'||PUT(today(), yymmddn8.) as t1.SourceFile
```

Hand coded example (versus EG visual join):

```
proc sql;
  create table x as 
  select 
    'ULPDT_'||PUT(today(), yymmddn8.) as SourceFile
  from 
    sashelp.class(obs=1)
  ;
```

Comment: I'll second the YYMMDD, I've never seen YYDDMM used in any setting.